# Openshift - auth: couldn't find user while connecting mongodb via mongojs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, restify, mongojs

I am following this tutorial to host a Rest API at my openshift account:

[Day 27: Restify–Build Correct REST Web Services in Node.js](https://blog.openshift.com/day-27-restify-build-correct-rest-web-services-in-nodejs/)

As per my requirements I made few changes, below is the code:

**server.js**

```
var restify = require('restify');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');

var ip_addr = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var port    =  process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

var server = restify.createServer({name: 'bemeta'});
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.CORS());

server.listen(port, ip_addr, function(){
              console.log(server.name + ' listening at url ' + server.url);
              });

var connectionString = '127.0.0.1:27017/bemeta';

if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
    connectionString = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ':' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + '@' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
}

var db = mongojs(connectionString, ['bemeta']);
var beRecords = db.collection("be_records");

var PATH = '/be_records';

// get all records
server.get({path: PATH, version:'0.0.1'}, findAllRecords);

// create new record
server.post({path: PATH, version:'0.0.1'}, createRecord);

// defining call backs
function findAllRecords(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    beRecords.find(function(err, docs){
                   console.log('Response docs ' + docs);
                   console.log('Error '+ err);

                   if(docs){
                   res.send(200, docs);
                   return next();
                   }

                   return next(err);
                   });
}


function createRecord(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    var beRecord = {};
    beRecord.be_id = req.params.be_id;
    beRecord.item_title = req.params.item_title;
    beRecord.item_description = req.params.item_description;
    beRecord.item_link = req.params.item_link;

    beRecords.save(beRecord, function(err, docs){
                   console.log('Response docs ' + docs);
                   console.log('Error '+ err);
                   if(docs){
                   res.send(201, beRecord);
                   return next();
                   }
                   else {
                   next(err);
                   }
                   });
}
```

When I run it at local and fire a get request via postman by typing below url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/be_records
```

I get response as: `[]`, which is correct since I have not inserted any document in respective collection.

But when I run it at my openshift account and fire a get request via postman by typing below url:

```
http://bemeta-{domain-name}.rhcloud.com/be_records
```

I get response as:

```
{
  "code": "InternalError",
  "message": "auth fails"
}
```

In my rhc console I see below messages:

```
==> app-root/logs/mongodb.log <==
Wed Feb 24 01:32:23.543 [conn3]  authenticate db: bemeta { authenticate: 1, user: "admin", nonce: "some nonce", key: "some key" }
Wed Feb 24 01:32:23.544 [conn3] auth: couldn't find user admin@bemeta, bemeta.system.users
```

I am not sure why is it trying to find user - admin@bemeta, might be I am missing something over here, I do not have any such user but I do have an admin user which is used to connect to mongodb.

Here is the snapshot of my db (as shown in RockMongo):

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to authenticate the admin user for your `bemeta` db? You can do that in RockMongo: slect the db -> More -> Authentication -> Add user

Comment: I have authenticated the admin user for db `bemta` but now on firing the get request I am getting this error: '<title>502 Proxy Error</title> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request. <ahref="/be_records">GET&nbsp;/be_records</a> Reason: Error reading from remote server

Comment: The `502 Proxy Error` error got resolved after I restarted the app on openshift :) Hey @JiriFiala why don't you add your comment as answer, I will mark it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auth error was caused by not having the `admin` user authenticated for accessing the `bemeta` database (see question comments above for details).

Users can be authenticated using the RockMongo interface as follows:
Select a DB -> More -> Authentication -> Add user.